# Strip everything ater second slash

Tags: php, character, strpos

If I have the following URL:

http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame

how do i use php to remove everything after the last "/"?

So I would be left with:

http://www.mysite.com/games/

I have tried this:

```
    $currentUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame';     
    $newstr = substr($currentUrl, 0, strpos($currentUrl, '/', strpos($currentUrl, '/')+4));
```

Comment: Thanks..what if i want to remove everything after the second "/" ? So it would leave me with 'http://www.mysite.com/' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
print_r (dirname('http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$currentUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame';     
$newstr = substr($currentUrl, 0, strrpos($currentUrl, '/'));
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/re9X0G7c)**.

Comment: Thanks..what if i want to remove everything after the second "/" ? So it would leave me with 'mysite.com/'; ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $newstr = substr($currentUrl, 0, strrchr($currentUrl, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions to pick out parts from a path.

like:

- basename() - Returns trailing name component of path
- pathinfo() - Returns information about a file path
- realpath() - Returns canonicalized absolute pathname

but maybe ***pathinfo()*** is best suited for your needs:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame/cool.php';

$path_parts = pathinfo($file);

echo $path_parts['dirname'] . "<br />";
echo $path_parts['basename'] . "<br />";
echo $path_parts['extension'] . "<br />";
echo $path_parts['filename'] . "<br />"; // since PHP 5.2.0

?>
```

Output:

```
http://www.mysite.com/games/topgame
cool.php
php
cool
```

Start searching here... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php